# Шевлюга и шевляга — от французского cheval?

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что слово *шевлюга* (шевляга) произошло от французского cheval?

Answer (score 3):

Вы имеете в виду устаревшее ругательство? Видимо, того же происхождения, что и "шваль". Тогда Ваше предположение верно, от фр.cheval - лошадь, конь.

Одна из версий его появления:

> Потомственные французские дворяне называли себя «chevalier», по-русски
>   «шевалье» — всадник, рыцарь, кавалер. Еще по средневековым правилам
>   дворянин всегда представлялся в момент пленения именно так: титул
>   давал ему возможность остаться в живых, так как представителей знати
>   обычно из темницы выкупали. Вот и в войне 1812 года французы, попадая
>   к русским в плен, сразу начинали кричать: «Шевалье!». Наши же шутили в
>   ответ: «Опять какая-то ободранная шваль. Где ваши маршалы?». Надо
>   отметить, что вид французских пленников было крайне истощенным.

По иной популярной версии слово «шваль» возникло тогда, когда французы-оккупанты, занимая русские деревни, требовали у крестьян лошадей. Они кричали им «Шваль!», что означало: «подайте лошадь». Крестьяне же считали, будто швалью именуют их. И в ответ также стали называть французов: «Опять эта шваль приехала, коней забрать хочет».

Подробнее здесь:

https://denis-balin.livejournal.com/2736579.html

Comment: Фёдор Шевляга это русская фамилия или калькированная?

Comment: Эта фамилия от прозвища Шевляга (или Шевлюга) означает «кляча», ономастики  говорят о русском происхождении прозвища, но есть и другое мнение, что всё от того же французского cheval , так называли на Руси  медлительных людей (кляча). А вот прозвище его брата Андрея Ивановича  Кобылы - неверно транскрибированное имя его предка Гланды Камбилы Дивоновича (Камбила-Кобыла) https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/5044159/post253331701/

Comment: В древнерусском языке слово «шевляга» означает «тощая лошадёнка». http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%91%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0